# Unable to install BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently using..

- Mac OS X

I've attempted to use `easy_install BeautifulSoup4` and `python setup.py install` but I keep receiving the error message such as..

`python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `pip install BeautifulSoup4`?

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade)`  I've tested numerous times times on the python IDLE but it comes up with the same message `ImportError: No module named 'bs4'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's not in our path.   From the python interpreter, do the following to confirm:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.path)
```

Mine gave me something like this:

```
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.5.3-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ldap_target_ctl-0.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

Check that Beautiful Soup shows up in that list OR is in one of the directories in that list (like /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages).

All else fails, remove it and try installing again.

```
pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4
```

Then try re-installing.